# SQS Message Delay Not Working As Expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm trying send individual SQS messages with a delay.  Using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-send-message-with-timer.html to test message delays, I'm not seeing any delay.

If I set a delay on the queue, that delay is honoured, however not for individual messages.  I'm doing the following (all from the AWS console):

- Open the SQS console and right click on my test queue - verify that there the delay value for the queue is 0.
- Right click on the test queue and click 'Send a Message'
- Add a message body
- Set 'Delay delivery of this message by' to 30 seconds
- Click Send Message.
- Receive a confirmation stating 'Your message has been sent and will be ready to be received in 30 seconds.'

However when I check CloudWatch I can see that the message was delivered almost immediately.  I'm I misunderstanding something, or have I missed something in the configuration?

Comment: How is the message being consumed? Do you have a Lambda function attached, or your own program?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, there is a Lambda function attached - at the moment it just writes to the log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My testing shows that messages sent to an SQS queue which a Lambda function is using as a trigger will **immediately trigger the Lambda function**, even if a Delay setting is provided.

See: [amazon sqs - How do I return a message back to SQS from lambda trigger - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818930/174777)

Comment: Thanks! That’s definitely the behaviour I’m seeing!